# mouseover tooltip using django

Tags: django

How can I make a simple mouseover tooltip using django?
Let's say, I have a list of products in a table, and when I mouseover one of them, I can see a box with short description and producer. The tooltip should disappear right after moving cursor out of table cell.

Comment: This isn't a Django question at all. This is going to be a JS exercise.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with the title attribute entirely in HTML (aka in your django template). HTML 5 allows the attribute for all tags, HTML 4.01 only for selected elements.
See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp

Comment: Is there a way to make it pop-up instantly? Right now I have to mouseover it for ~1 second and don't move cursor to see the tooltip - some people might not catch it. Of course js is the more elegent way, but this one is so simple and pretty much all I need right now.

Answer (score 2):

I used this for a model form that already had the 'help txt' attributes assigned in the model - potenitally the formatting of the HTML could be better, it works well though providing a table of Model Form fields with toll tips if the 'help txt' attribute has been set. It's a combo of HTML, DJNAGO and JSCRIPT.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<table>
    {% for field in form %}
    <tr>
        {% if field.help_text %}
            <td>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="{{ field.help_text|safe }}">{{field.label}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ field }}
            </td>

        {% else %}
            <td>
                 {{ field.label }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ field }}
            </td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

</table>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap popover + Ajax $.get when mouse over fire a Ajax to get the data you want to display and show up popover with those data content

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Bootstrap Tooltips](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp). Simple and easy.